# Return auto generated column values from sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, c#-3.0

How to return auto generated column values from sqlite database in c#. I'm using Sqlite.data.dll.

Tried by executing query : "select last_insert_rowid() but it doesn;t seem to work as it is returning 0s. I'm using SqliteDataReader object to get the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried these commands, and it worked fine (even if the `last_insert_rowid()` call is from another transaction):

```
sqlite> create table mytable(pk integer primary key, other stuff);
sqlite> insert into mytable values(null, 42);
sqlite> select last_insert_rowid();
1
```

The only requirement of `last_insert_rowid()` is that it is called on the *same* database connection; please check that you didn't open another one.

Comment: Thanks...I was using different database connection for getting the autogenerated column, but using the same connection it is working fine.

Comment: Is this threadsafe? What if a different connection has inserted between your second and third statement (between `insert` and `select last_ins`...)?

Comment: @LimitedAtonement This is [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html).

Answer (score 0):

is your id is incremented? then try this:

SELECT max(id)

or you can refer to this post

[Click HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177323/how-to-read-the-last-row-with-sql-server)

Comment: ID column is autoincrement column and primary key. SELECT max(ID) works but is this the best way to retrieve the autogenerated column values?