# Getting the latest row with a condition from another table in MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, I have two tables, one called `carthead` and the other called `cartrows`. Each table is probably 10k rows. I have identity columns in both tables, `idorder` is an identity column in `carthead` and `idrow` is an identity column in `cartrows` (though I don't seem to need to use this, I think, but I'm including it here so you have the background).

I'm trying to find the newest (or last-entered) `idorder` number (again, an identity column) where a product # = 97 and imgexists is True (it's a flag that's set if we have an image of it).

This query runs:

```
SELECT TOP 1 cr.idorder 
FROM cartrows cr, carthead ch 
WHERE cr.idproduct = 97 
  AND ch.imgexists IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY cr.idorder DESC
```

However, the answer spits out a number for the latest row where idproduct = 97 but not taking into consideration ch.imgexists is not null (I've tried other variations, including <> '', is not False, etc with the same result).

I began my search finding this thread:
( [How to read the last row with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177323/how-to-read-the-last-row-with-sql-server) ) and just thinking I could add conditions to suit my needs, but apparently I'm doing it wrong..

Any thoughts?  Kind thanks to all from Austin, Texas..

Comment: you are forgetting a join condition... and i'd use explicit joins vs your comma seperated list in the from clause

Comment: gotcha; where would I add the join [and what kind?  INNER JOIN?].. for example,

Comment: you need to introduce a join condition between the two used tables, cartrows and carthead with using a where clause or a join clause.

Comment: I would recommend you stop using the `,` joins between the tables. In the long run it's going to be better if you always use `join` or `left outer join` etc.

Comment: so i have this:  SELECT top 1 cr.idorder FROM rossirovetti..cartrows cr, rossirovetti..carthead ch 
inner join carthead.idorder ch on cartrows.idorder cr
where cr.idproduct = 97 and ch.imgexists is not null ORDER BY cr.idorder DESC 

  ...  but it breaks: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'cr'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join condition to limit the rows returned... something like

```
SELECT top 1 
   cr.idorder 
FROM 
   cartrows cr
INNER JOIN 
   carthead ch on
   ch.idproduct = cr.idproduct  --or what ever the tables are related by...
WHERE 
   cr.idproduct = 97 
   and ch.imgexists is not null 
ORDER BY 
   cr.idorder DESC
```

Also, I'd take a [look at this post regarding your joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

@scsimon had the right answer here, I need to do more studying on JOINS in general; thank y'all for the help..

```
SELECT top 1 
   cr.idorder 
FROM 
   cartrows cr
INNER JOIN 
   carthead ch on
   ch.idorder = cr.idorder
WHERE 
   cr.idproduct = 97 
   and ch.imgexists is not null 
ORDER BY 
   cr.idorder DESC
```

worked.. ;-)