# SQL where Key = "Test" and ID = max(ID)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

How do I select a row with a key where ID equals to the max ID. Since ID is automatically generated as a unique primary key.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Key = "Test" AND WHERE ID = max(ID)
```

I've tried, but it executes but returns blank.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Key= "Test" AND ID=(SELECT max(ID) FROM Table);
```

Comment: You are almost correct, you forgotten inner query condition: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID=(SELECT max(ID) FROM Table  Where Key= "Test");`

Comment: If you move the `WHERE` clause to the subquery, you'll get better results

Comment: Group by key and look for max(ID) in the group.

Comment: Works now after I've added Where Key= "Test" to the subquery. Thank you both Mani and HoneyBadger.

Comment: Is there a way to call every column (*) except ID column?

Comment: @DamnSpaceship That is a different question and should be asked separately, but the short answer is no. You have to list all columns, or use `*`, there is no *everything, but* construct in SQL (speaking about column list here).
In general, using `*` is considered as bad practice (Except when used in `COUNT(*)` - counting rows or in `EXISTS (SELECT *...)` - checking if row exists).
List the columns you need in the SELECT

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what you mean by `MAX(id)`. Is that the max on the whole table, or just of the rows where `Key = 'Test'`?

Answer (score 2):

your query is missing 'WHERE' clause in the inner query it should look something like this

```
SELECT * FROM [TableName] WHERE ID=(SELECT max(ID) FROM [TableName] WHERE Key= "Test");
```

there is another way mentioned on another similar question

`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [TABLENAME] WHERE Key="Test" ORDER BY ID DESC`

reference : [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177323/how-to-read-the-last-row-with-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Very probably, the newest row - the one that got the highest `id` so far, has a value for `key` other than 'Test'.

So you can only get the row - among the rows whose `key` is equal to 'Test' - with the highest `id` .

Therefore, try:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE key='Test'
  AND id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table WHERE key='Test')
```